# script Param allows optional argument and ValueFromRemainingArguments

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

***tl;dr*** a PowerShell script `Param` section that allows an optional argument followed by a `ValueFromRemainingArguments` argument?

I want a script that takes an optional argument value `int` when passed `-argInt` and all other arguments become appended to an array `String[]`. `argInt` would default to `0`.

So given file `my-args.ps1` with script body

```powershell
Write-Host "argInt is $argInt"

foreach($arg in $argsRemaining) {
    Write-Host "arg is $arg"
}
```

Calls would look like

```text
PS> .\my-args.ps1 foo bar
argInt is 0
arg is foo
arg is bar

PS> .\my-args.ps1 -argInt 33 foo bar
argInt is 33
arg is foo
arg is bar

PS> .\my-args.ps1 -argInt foo
my-args.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'argInt'. Cannot convert value "foo" to type "System.Int32".

PS> .\my-args.ps1
my-args.ps1: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'argsRemaining'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
```

What should the `Param` declaration look like?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#mandatory-argument

Answer (score 0):

This would accomplish what you're asking, for the last call, I would advise making that parameter `Mandatory` instead otherwise, you must validate that it is not null at runtime as shown in the function's body.

```bash
function Test-Param {
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter()]
        [int] $argInt = 0,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments, Position = 0)]
        [string[]] $argsRemaining
    )

    if (-not $argsRemaining) {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
            [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
                # Can add a custom message as 2nd Argument here:
                [System.ArgumentNullException]::new('argsRemaining'),
                'NullRemainingArgument',
                [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidArgument,
                $argsRemaining))
    }

    Write-Host "argInt is $argInt"

    foreach ($arg in $argsRemaining) {
        Write-Host "arg is $arg"
    }
}

Test-Param foo bar
Test-Param -argInt 33 foo bar
Test-Param -argInt foo
Test-Param
```

Answer (score 0):

[PositionalBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.3#positionalbinding) is another alternative you can use to achieve your goal:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int] $argInt,
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]]$argsRemaining
)
```

In case you want some parameters to stay positional - this can be specified explicitly - e.g.:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][string] $operationName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int] $argInt,
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]]$argsRemaining
)
```